# Saving in Elasticsearch with Spark Streaming issue

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch, spark-streaming

I am trying to save in Elasticsearch using Spark Streaming. The code works, but it only saves to elastic search once i stop the process (i am launching it from intelliJ IDEA). 
i need to save twitts as long as they come in streaming.

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
tweets.foreachRDD(tweet => {
  if (tweet.isEmpty) {
    println("no se han recibido tweets en este tramo de tiempo")
  } else {
    val tweetsRdd = tweet.map(t => {
      System.out.println(t.getText)
      var country = ""
      if (t.getPlace() != null) {
        country = t.getPlace().getCountry()
      }
      val hashtag = t.getText().split(" ").filter(word => word.startsWith("#"))
      Tweet(t.getUser().getName(), t.getUser().getLang(), t.getText(), t.getCreatedAt(), t.getRetweetCount(), country, t.isRetweet(), t.getUser().getFollowersCount(), hashtag)

    })
    EsSpark.saveToEs(tweetsRdd, index_name + "/" + type_name)

  }
}
)

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```